# blazor wasm + oidc - why http 500 code when on api calls in prod? on debug all ok

Tags: c#, blazor, authorization, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

i have some blazor wasm that use external oidc
so i have it like this:
wasm:

```cs
 builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(opt =>
   {
       opt.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://xx.yy.pl/auth/realms/corporate";
       opt.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "#ClienID"; 
       opt.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
      
   });

var IHttpServiceClient = builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IBaseHttpService,BaseHttpService>((serviceProvider, client) =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
IHttpServiceClient.AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

and CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler is simply

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler:AuthorizationMessageHandler
{

    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider , NavigationManager nav) :base(provider, nav)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { nav.BaseUri });
    }
}
```

and now server api: (if i remove this part everything works when not `[authorize]` )

```cs
 builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {      
        options.Authority = "https://xx.yy.pl/auth/realms/corporate";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
    });
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
    });
```

and on debug time this works perfectly fine - when im logged in - it grabs tokens and add to request for server sends/recives all ok

but when i did publish and sended it into my PROD server
then all api request fails  / throw 500..  and client throw:

```
      Unhandled exception rendering component: 
System.Exception
   at Web.Client.Core.HttpClients.BaseHttpService.<sendRequest>d__11`1[[Web.Shared.WeatherForecast[], Web.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at Web.Client.Core.HttpClients.BaseHttpService.<Get>d__5`1[[Web.Shared.WeatherForecast[], Web.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at Web.Client.Pages.Learn.FetchData3.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task , ComponentState )
```

i see all requests ends up with BadRequest with no message and no content

**am i missing something here? what may be wrong with this configuration ?**
i see that token is added to body correctly
[image]

please advice
best regards

edit
logs from server

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer 
Connection ID "14987979565794590827", Request ID "8000006c-0001-d000-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
Exception occurred while processing message.
IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
```

Comment: In production, these settings are not set, so you might need to look into this part

      if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
       {.....}

Comment: i updated sory - it was part of my debugging and searching for problem - wythout this if problem is still the same sorry - it redirrects to this oidc ok , i can sing in - ok i get redirrect to my app as logged user - ok but api calls fails

Comment: see my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: i googlet that :) checked options.IncludeErrorDetails=true but nothing changed. You write there If you get other status codes, this means it is likely that problem is elsewhere. Such as,400 bad request or500 server error. but if i simpli remove builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer") part then when no [authorize] it works fine so it is this middleware issue 4shure. monday will try this log part on server thanks. also do You known if it may be connectivity issue? between server api and this https://xx.yy.pl/auth/realms/corporate ?does api sends / recives something also there to verify?

Comment: @ToreNestenius i have logs -updated  - dumb me was not checkint this. does You known what can cause this errors ? lack of connectivity to this authority as i wrote?

Comment: ok this is it 4shure - i was thinking that server does need - all it need is token this but it does.  i added  IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //Add this line and now error is 
IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: ' xx.yy.pl/auth/realms/corporate/.well-known/openid-configuration'. thank You for reminding about this server logs

Comment: Glad I could help you diagnose the problem, let me know if you find something that I should add to my blog post. Also let me know how you decided to solve your problem.

Comment: maybe please consider adding / changing this part "If you get other status codes, this means it is likely that problem is elsewhere. Such as, 400 bad request or 500 server error."- here are details how my issue produce 500 when canot obtain for example this configuration https://help.akana.com/content/current/cm/api_oauth/oauth_discovery/m_oauth_getOpenIdConnectWellknownConfiguration.htm  "500 - An error occurred processing the call.". And for the fix i think i will just open this route from server if needed - are there other options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the API can't reach the authorization server from within your system. How to solve it all depends on your configuration, but you need to ensure that the domain that you provide in opt.ProviderOptions.Authority is actually reachable from within your system.

Or use a different URL/domain for it.

Just because your browser can reach it, does not mean that it is reachable from within the backend.

Comment: for future - do You known if this server/api need only this .well-known/openid-configuration json fot knowing config of tokens? or api is constantly 'speaking' with this oidc also? for every request it contacts this oidc to confirm that key is still valid? i dont think so but have no idea how it really works on server side beside checking token params / time validation and making user out of it ?

Comment: AddOpenIDConnect and AddJwtBearer both downloads the configuration and the JWKS keys once every 24 hour by default.  You can also manually provide the keys, but that I think is a bad idea unless you really need to. In general it only need to download the publick-key part of the signing key so it can validate the received tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the info ;) od You known some article od how to add them manually please post - just to known / until security guys allow to open this route etc. Does this keys change sometime? thanks again and regads!

Comment: When and if they keys change. depends on the setup in the authorization server. Usually, it is the best to just download the keys and let the client self-configure. Also as the token provider might use multiple different keys over time.